# How to test Angular component, which include Ajs upgraded services and components?

Tags: angular, unit-testing

When I trying to run test, I get an error like "$injector provider missing".

So I try to provide $injector manually:

```
module(require('ccmSfaWelcomePage'));
inject(function ($injector) {
  injector = $injector;
});
```

and add it to testModule like

```
providers: [
    { provide: '$injector', useValue: injector }
]
```

After that I'm getting error like "$scope provider missing".

So, help me please, how to correctly provide angularjs runtime to Angular unit-
test.